# Ubuntu 14.10 cpufreq not working (not pstate problem)

Tags: 14.10, cpufreq

About a 4-year old HP Laptop with a 2.8GHz i7, 8GB RAM.  Has been upgraded individually from 11.04 through to 14.10, skipping 13.10.

Since 13.04, after booting, cpufreq-info reports:

current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 1.20 GHz.

and the CPU is stuck there, no amount of adjusting with cpufreq-set does anything.

The only way I've found to adjust it is to first do a "su -s" (sudo does not work for this specific set of operations), and then:

```
echo 2800000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo 2800000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo 2800000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
echo 2800000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

and then the CPU will scale as normal. Any ideas how to fix this so that it stays permanent?